# Repeater ViewState not refreshing INPUT

Tags: asp.net, .net, viewstate

I had a `Repeater` with `ViewState` disabled and several input controls with `ViewState` enabled. After I would postback and rebind the data based off of various selections the `INPUT` controls didn't update. They kept the same state they had before the postback.

To elaborate if my filter was X and I had two inputs, the first one in state X1 and the second one in state X2. If I switched my filter to Y the inputs would be still in state X1 and X2 respectively.

Turning `ViewState` on fixed this. My question is why? I excluded most of the code because it was boiler plate. You can bind a list of integers to the `Repeater` and then if the integer was odd or even and set the `Checkbox` to that value it would function as my boiler plate code did/does.

Below is pseudocode.

```
<asp:repeater EnableViewState="false">
   <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:checkbox runat="server" id="foo" EnableViewState="True">
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EnableViewState` property will override any child controls which in your case you are trying to enable.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.enableviewstate(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the server control persists
>   its view state, **and the view state of any child controls it contains**,
>   to the requesting client.

and

> The ViewStateMode property for the control is set to Enabled or inherits the Enabled setting.

So having the `Repeater`'s `EnableViewState` property set to `false` is forcing all your child controls to also be set to false regardless of you indicating at the control level that you want it to be `true`.

Comment: Why would this cause the input to not refresh on post back? Should I include a small code sample?

Comment: @gh9 Because `ViewState` is turned off for the child controls because of the `Repeater` being set to off, all controls will not reflect any new values on `PostBack`, they will just appear as default indicated by the markup.  The `ViewState` is what is used to maintain the updated changes between `PostBacks` and because it is disabled, this is not maintained and why you are not seeing your changes reflected.  Turning `ViewState` on at the `Repeater` level enables the controls to use `ViewState` and thus reflect changes made.